# finding user current location using Google Maps API (Google Places)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to know the user's current location using Google. I know how to get the user's altitude and longitude using the mapKit but i don't know how to translate it as a location or an address (street name, city, country). I did a few search and all I found was using NSURL to access a given link that accesses the Google Places. however, the one available is to list the places nearby the user. so how can I know the user's current location? 
Note: I'm not using Apple's Map since my country isn't included and Google is more supporting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reverse geocoding services.

Here are the docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding

Example request (JSON):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

Get JSON data on iOS:

[Not getting json response in google query of longitude and latitude in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502961/not-getting-json-response-in-google-query-of-longitude-and-latitude-in-ios)

For parsing JSON object in iOS, this answer could be usefull for you:

[How to parse specific googlemaps API webservices JSON repsonse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634810/how-to-parse-specific-googlemaps-api-webservices-json-repsonse)

Comment: okay, i created the NSURL and i obtained the latitude and longitude how do i continue from here? how do i download the JSON file and extract the address from it? i'm not the skilled at using JSON files. Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: the post you recommended is really useful but they suppose you have the JSON file. actually i'm not knowing how to download it first. any hint?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use the Web API, the iOS SDK already handles this using the `GMSGeocoder` class. Here's an example in Swift of how to convert the user's current location into an address:

```
let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(currentLocation.coordinate) { (response, error) -> Void in

        print("Response: \(response.firstResult())")
        print("Error: \(error)")

    }
```